# Monolithic modular web application in .NET Core 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing, asp.net-core-7.0

I want to develop a web application separated in modules. Suppose, for example, one module for authentication, one for products catalog, one for products and one for customers.

When using Visual Studio 2022, I created some Web Api projects. The problem I have is that all projects contain a Program.cs file and all projects have a diferent web port assigned by Visual Studio project template.

What should I do? should I create an "entry point" project which will have a Program.cs file  and delete Program.cs from the other projects? If that is the case, how can I load the assemblies belonging to the other projects so that I can access controllers and views from the other assemblies?

EDIT:

I have used examples in this page to create my application: https://www.thinktecture.com/en/asp-net-core/modular-monolith/

I created a project called `EntryPoint.Core` which has this `Program.cs` file:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers().ConfigureApplicationPartManager(manager =>
{
    // Clear all auto detected controllers.
    manager.ApplicationParts.Clear();

    // Add feature provider to allow "internal" controller
    manager.FeatureProviders.Add(new InternalControllerFeatureProvider());
});

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// Register a convention allowing to us to prefix routes to modules.
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPostConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>, ModuleRoutingMvcOptionsPostConfigure>();

builder.Services.AddModule<Modules.Authenticate.Core.Startup>("/Api/Authenticate", builder.Configuration);

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRouting();

var modules = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IEnumerable<Module>>();
foreach (var module in modules)
{
    app.Map($"/{module.RoutePrefix}", ab =>
    {
        ab.UseRouting();
        module.Startup.Configure(ab, builder.Configuration);
    });
}

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

On the other hand, I have the `Modules.Authenticate.Core` project which has this `Startup.cs` file:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<SecuWebModulesAuthenticateContext>(options =>
        {
            options
                .UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
   #if DEBUG
            options.LogTo(Console.WriteLine);
   #endif
        });

        // Agrega autenticación
        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
                options.ReturnUrlParameter = "ReturnUrl";
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = configuration["AuthJwt:Issuer"],
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = configuration["AuthJwt:Audience"],
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    RequireExpirationTime = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["AuthJwt:Key"] ?? string.Empty))
                };
            });

        services.AddAuthorization();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            endpoints.MapPost("/Api/Authenticate/CreateToken", [AllowAnonymous] async (string usuario, string clave) =>
            {
                var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SecuWebModulesAuthenticateContext>();
                optionsBuilder = optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    #if DEBUG
                optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine);
    #endif
                using (SecuWebModulesAuthenticateContext db = new(optionsBuilder.Options))
                {
                    ApiAcceso? acceso = await db.ApiAcceso.FirstOrDefaultAsync(aa => aa.ApiAccesoEliminadoEn == null && !aa.ApiAccesoBloqueado && aa.ApiAccesoUsuario == usuario && aa.ApiAccesoClave == clave);
                    if (acceso is not null)
                    {
                        var issuer = configuration["AuthJwt:Issuer"];
                        var audience = configuration["AuthJwt:Audience"];
                        var key = configuration["AuthJwt:Key"];
                        if (key is not null)
                        {
                            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                            {
                                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                                {
                                    new Claim("Id", acceso.ApiAccesoId.ToString()),
                                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, acceso.ApiAccesoUsuario),
                                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                                }),
                                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5),
                                Issuer = issuer,
                                Audience = audience,
                                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature)
                            };
                            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
                            var jwtToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
                            var stringToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
                            return Results.Ok(stringToken);
                        }
                    }

                    return Results.Unauthorized();
                }
            })
        ); 
    }
```

Finally, I have a project called `Modules.Integration` which defines the following helper classes:

```
public class Module
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the route prefix to all controller and endpoints in the module.
    /// </summary>
    public string RoutePrefix { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the startup class of the module.
    /// </summary>
    public IModuleStartup Startup { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the assembly of the module.
    /// </summary>
    public Assembly Assembly => Startup.GetType().Assembly;

    public Module(string routePrefix, IModuleStartup startup)
    {
        RoutePrefix = routePrefix;
        Startup = startup;
    }
}

public class ModuleRoutingConvention : IActionModelConvention
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Module> _modules;

    public ModuleRoutingConvention(IEnumerable<Module> modules)
    {
        _modules = modules;
    }

    public void Apply(ActionModel action)
    {
        var module = _modules.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Assembly == action.Controller.ControllerType.Assembly);
        if (module == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        action.RouteValues.Add("module", module.RoutePrefix);
    }
}

public class ModuleRoutingMvcOptionsPostConfigure : IPostConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Module> _modules;

    public ModuleRoutingMvcOptionsPostConfigure(IEnumerable<Module> modules)
    {
        _modules = modules;
    }

    public void PostConfigure(string? name, MvcOptions options)
    {
        options.Conventions.Add(new ModuleRoutingConvention(_modules));
    }
}

public static class ModuleServiceCollection
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a module.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services"></param>
    /// <param name="routePrefix">The prefix of the routes to the module.</param>
    /// <typeparam name="TStartup">The type of the startup class of the module.</typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IServiceCollection AddModule<TStartup>(this IServiceCollection services, string routePrefix, IConfiguration configuration)
        where TStartup : IModuleStartup, new()
    {
        // Register assembly in MVC so it can find controllers of the module
        services.AddControllers().ConfigureApplicationPartManager(manager =>
            manager.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(typeof(TStartup).Assembly)));

        var startup = new TStartup();
        startup.ConfigureServices(services, configuration);

        services.AddSingleton(new Module(routePrefix, startup));

        return services;
    }
}
```

When I run the `EntryPortal.Core` project, swagger recognizes the route `/Api/Authenticate/CreateToken`, however, when I try to test it, a 404 error is thrown.

What else is missing in order the route to be recognized?

EDIT 2:

I realized that `ModuleRoutingConvention.Apply` method is not being called in my project but in the example project from that page, it is.

I noted that the Apply method, in the example code, is called in this statement:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
```

In my case, I am using `app.MapControllers()` since when I used above instruction, a warning was shown telling that I need to use top level route registration. However, I used both ways to register routes and in neither case, the Apply method was called.

EDIT 3:

I realized that it works when I create a controller and an action in the module.

If I use `endpoints.MapPost` and I include the action code inside, a 404 error is shown, even when Swagger does show the route in its page.

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: Your program.cs is the "composition root" that brings all your dependencies together. Including "application parts" that exist in other assemblies. But I wouldn't load those assemblies dynamically. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Have you tried the suggested way? Do need any further assistence on this?

Comment: Hello @MdFaridUddinKiron I was lost using that link but it seems that was not I was looking for. I found this other article: https://www.thinktecture.com/en/asp-net-core/modular-monolith/ which shows exactly what I need. However, the example I found there is for .NET Core 5 with Program and Startup classes hosting model. .NET Core 7 uses other model. I tried to use Startup class but I could not change the current model to use the old hosting model.

Comment: Thanks for your response and sharing the details, but I think startup.cs configuration should act exactly in program.cs file if there is no other dependency remain.

Comment: if you really want to do this then do it in .net 5 follow the guide and then see how to migrate to .net 7, like you say the difference is just the startup stuff.. aka newer stuff they reduced the number of files... but then made this type of intergration/config "harder" so if there no way then just setup your .net 7 like the 5 and call it a day. Would love to see the practical version of this... like if its 100+ endpoints then why not simple run as two....

Comment: like jeremy said,  instead of showing all the code which is not appliable it would of been been to show your project structure so we can see which project the "composition root" in the example its Monolith.Host and you can see the wiring here https://github.com/thinktecture-labs/aspnetcore-modular-monolith/blob/main/Monolith.Host/Startup.cs

Comment: @jstuardo can you please post some [mre] somewhere like on github? With some example apps showing what you want to support.

Comment: Last weeks I partecipate to a Global Azure conference in Turin, and [Alberto Acerbis](https://albertoacerbis.com/) presented a solution to use a modular architecture for a monolithic application (eventually reusable when some module needs to be split in a separate service). This is a link to on of the repositories that he created to explain this approach [BrewUp repository](https://github.com/BrewUp/BrewUp). He used minimal APIs to simplify modules definitions. Take a look.

Comment: @jstuardo can you please provide full [mre] (for example add code to some github repo) and list of problems needed to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 6 and NET 7, Microsoft has Unifies Startup.cs and Program.cs into a single Program.cs file.([Web app template improvements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-6.0?view=aspnetcore-7.0#web-app-template-improvements))

Modules.Authenticate.Core project Move code to the program.cs

can you try Microsoft's Areas provides a way to partition an ASP.NET Core 7 Web app into smaller functional groups, each with its own set of Razor Pages, controllers, views, and models.

Microsoft's [Areas in ASP.NET Core 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-7.0#areas-with-razor-pages)
**Area folder structure**

- Project name

  - Areas

    - Customers

      - Controllers

        - HomeController.cs
      - Views

        - Home

          - Index.cshtml
    - Products

      - Controllers

        - HomeController.cs
      - Views

        - Home

          - Index.cshtml

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
        options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
        options.ReturnUrlParameter = "ReturnUrl";
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(x=>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = builder.configuration["AuthJwt:Issuer"],
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience=builder.configuration["AuthJwt:Audience"],
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    RequireExpirationTime = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["AuthJwt:Key"] ?? string.Empty))
                };
                };

            });


app.MapAreaControllerRoute(
    name: "MyAreaCustomers",
    areaName: "Customers",
    pattern: "Customers/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapAreaControllerRoute(
    name: "MyAreaProducts",
    areaName: "Products",
    pattern: "Products/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
    <li>
        <a asp-area="Customers" asp-page="/Index">
           customers/Index
        </a>
    </li>

<li>
 @Html.ActionLink("Products/Home/Index", "Index", "Home",new { area = "Products" })
</li>
```

Comment: _"Microsoft has removed the Startup.cs class"_ - that is not true. You can still use generic hosting with Startup class. What Microsoft has done is they changed tempates to use new minimal hosting model. Also the Startup class here is just a POCO class implementing custom `IStartup` interface (a bit unfortunate naming, I would agree).

Comment: Thank you for the reminder, Guru Stron,I have revised my content, and it should be integrated

Comment: Finally I have used a Startup class and now it is working. I don't want to use areas because that way, I will get a very big application. I want to break that application in modules that can be independently developed.